# StandardScaler ValueError error with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-structures, keras

I am attempting to apply `StandardScaler()` to some training data held in a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. In the process I am getting a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

This usually occurs when one tries to pass an inappropriate data type into StandardScaler() (like a list), but this is just a pandas dataframe (which is somewhat standard for this type of work). The code looks like:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_new = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

This gives me the `ValueError` stated above. I have a looked at a number of other questions here related to this, and none of the solutions worked for me (most of them did not have the same dataframe type as I did).

My question is, how can I get my data scaled properly with this type of DataFrame? Or, how can I easily change the DataFrame to work with `StandardScaler()`?

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to organize the data in class for better representation

```
class models:
    def __init__(self):
        self.training_data = pd.read_csv(path + "training_data.csv",header=0)
        self.test_data = pd.read_csv(path + "target_data.csv",header=0)
        self.X_train = self.training_data[[f for f in list(self.training_data)]]
        self.y_train = self.training_data['target']

    def StandardScaler(self,x): #to unit variance
        model = preprocessing.StandardScaler(copy=False)
        return model.fit_transform(x)
```

Then you can call the function in main to return a fit and transformed list of X and Y